# How to make a website secured using https

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate

I am using amazon ec2 (apache2,ubuntu16.04) for my web application.I am trying to make my web app secure using ssl but i am unable to , steps i tried are -

step 1 : I have generated a key file and generated certificates

step 2 : Installed certificates in my server

step 3 : I have changed etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default.config  file to

```
    <virtualhost : 443>
   serveradmin      xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
   servername       xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
   serveralias      xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  DocumentRoot      /var/www/html/xxxxx
  SSLEngine         on
  SSLCertificateFile     /path of cer/
  SSLCertificateKeyFile  /path of key/
  SSLCertificateChainFile  /path of cer/
```

step4 : Restared apache and application.

```
Any help will be thankful.
```

Comment: Could you please expand upon what you are "unable" to do? How do you test it and what error messages or problems are you facing? Feel free to Edit your question to add more information.

Comment: I got some certificates from private CA from a private organisation and i have installed certificates by using "sudo update-ca-certificates" in their servers, restarted apache2
   changed default.config as mentioned above.Restarted apache2 but still didnt get my url with https

Answer (score 0):

That's a bad idea.

You should use aws certificate manager to generate your ssl cert.
But instead of downloading them, you attach them to a Application Load Balancer which should point to your machine.

To sum up, aws will handle ssl through load balancer and route the traffic to your instance using plain http.

And bonus: your application you have a valid ssl. The way you are doing things your site will end up looking like this:

[image]